# Boost parse date/time string and yield .NET-compatible Ticks value

Tags: c++, .net, datetime, boost

I'd like to use C++/Boost to parse time strings such as `1980.12.06 21:12:04.232` and acquire a `ticks` value that would correspond to the tick count( used to initialize .NET's `System.DateTime`).  How can I do it?

*Update:* I *do* need to use C++; I cannot use C++/CLI for this.

Comment: Just realized, are you *actually* using .NET, or you just want the value to be the same as what .NET provides without actually *using* .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- in .Net Date time starts from 01.01.01 00:00:00
- in boost ptime starts from 1400.01.01 00.00.00

//c++ code

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    using namespace boost::gregorian;

    //C# offset till 1400.01.01 00:00:00
    uint64_t netEpochOffset = 441481536000000000LL;

    ptime ptimeEpoch(date(1400,1,1), time_duration(0,0,0));

    //note: using different format than yours, you'll need to parse the time in a different way
    ptime time = from_iso_string("19801206T211204,232");

    time_duration td = time - netEpoch;
    uint64_t nano = td.total_microseconds() * 10LL;

    std::cout <<"net ticks = " <<nano + netEpochOffset;

    return 0;
}
```

// outputs 624805819242320000

in c# to test

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(1400,1,1);
    Console.WriteLine(date.Ticks);

    DateTime date2 = new DateTime(624805819242320000L); //C++ output
    Console.WriteLine(date2);

            /*output
             * 441481536000000000
             * 6/12/1980 21:12:04
             * */
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net's "Ticks" is in 100-nanosecond intervals.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx

> ticksType: System.Int64 A date and time expressed in the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at
>   00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar

So you need the tick count of a known epoch (e.g. the Unix epoch), the number of days between the epoch and the desired date/time, and the time of day (`the total_nanoseconds accessor` may help). Then you can easily calculate the .Net equivalent tick count, with simple addition and multiplication.

You may still have issues to do with the representable range of dates.