# Standard conformant way of converting std::time_t to System::DateTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, c++-cli, mixed-mode, time-t

I have already found several answers related to converting a `std::time_t` value to `System::DateTime` and back. However, almost all answers seem to neglect that the type of `std::time_t` is actually undefined in the standard. Most solutions just cast `std::time_t` to whatever needed or apply arithmetic operations to a `std::time_t` object which is possible since it's an arithmetic type, but there is no specification about the result of such an operation. I know that *most* compilers define `time_t` as an `int` of some size but the fact alone that it has changed from `int32` to `int64` in many implementations recently shows that changes are indeed possible.

So I've come up with this solution which *should* work with any type of `std::time_t`. It works from what I have seen. But I was wondering - **Are there any possible pitfalls I might be unaware of?**

```
template <>
inline System::DateTime marshal_as(const std::time_t &from_object)
{
    // Returns DateTime in Local time format from time_t (assumed to be UTC)
    const auto unix_epoch = makeUtcTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    const auto unix_epoch_dt = System::DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, System::DateTimeKind::Utc);
    const auto secondsSinceEpoch = std::difftime(from_object, unix_epoch);
    return const_cast<System::DateTime&>(unix_epoch_dt).AddSeconds(secondsSinceEpoch).ToLocalTime();
} // end of System::DateTime marshal_as(const std::time_t &from_object)

template <>
inline std::time_t marshal_as(const System::DateTime &from_object)
{
    // Returns time_t in UTC format from DateTime
    auto from_dt = const_cast<System::DateTime&>(from_object).ToUniversalTime();
    return makeUtcTime(from_dt.Year, from_dt.Month, from_dt.Day, from_dt.Hour, from_dt.Minute, from_dt.Second);
} // end of std::time_t marshal_as(const System::DateTime &from_object)
```

3 assumptions were made:

- Resulting `std::time_t` should be in UTC since it doesn't contain any info on localization
- Resulting `System::DateTime` should be local time since `System::DateTime::Now` returns a localized `DateTime`
- `makeUtcTime` is a helper function creating a `std::tm` from the values supplied and creates a UTC `std::time_t` out of it. This is currently implemented using `_mkgmtime` because our interop code can safely rely on the existence of Microsoft extensions. However, a UTC version of `mktime` is readily available in other compilers as well (standard `mktime` expects local time).

2 less important things to consider:

- The `const_cast` is necessary because the marshal_as-template expects a `const T&` as parameter and I can't access the properties of a const .NET value-type object. However there might be a better solution.
- Should the `unix_epoch...` stuff be `static const`?

(I wasn't sure if this should be posted on "Programmers Exchange" since it's more of a discussion but since it's a very specific C++ question I thought SO might be the better place to ask)

Comment: There are two possible time_t definitions, depending on whether _USE_32BIT_TIME_T is defined.  If defined, it will work for as long as 32-bit time_t works.  System::DateTime is 64 bit.

Comment: That's true, thanks for the info. But since the resulting time_t in the second marshal_as is constructed using the calendar-values (Year, Month, ...), the worst thing that can happen is that the time_t is returned as (time_t)(-1), which basically means the conversion failed because the chosen time_t implementation can't represent the DateTime. But there you go, reason #1 why simply converting TotalSeconds to time_t might fail miserably.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864339/boost-parse-date-time-string-and-yield-net-compatible-ticks-value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It just isn't very productive to insist on a "standard conformant" way to make this conversion.  The only place where an std::time_t and a System::DateTime are ever going to meet is covered by the [Ecma-372 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm).  Of which there is right now, and surely will ever be, only **one** implementation.  The Mono project could be assumed to be the most likely source of another one, but right now they appear entirely uninterested in providing a mixed-mode implementation, the only reason you'd ever consider using C++/CLI.

std::time_t is steadily marching towards the Y2K38 disaster.  With Microsoft pre-emptively having done something about it, and really having to do so because they went for LLP64, but everybody else counting on their [LP64 data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLP64#64-bit_data_models) keeping them out of trouble.  In other words, no remaining 32-bit processors still running in 2038.  This could well be a self-fulfilling prophesy.

Regardless, the conversion is going to have to work with elapsed seconds since 1/1/1970.  And that can be a 32-bit or a 64-bit integral value, depending on implementation.  The only warranty I can give is that this code is at least good until 2038:

```
#include <ctime>

using namespace System;

public ref class Conversions {
public:
    static DateTime time_t2DateTime(std::time_t date) {
        double sec = static_cast<double>(date);
        return DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind::Utc).AddSeconds(sec);
    }
    static std::time_t DateTime2time_t(DateTime date) {
        TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        return static_cast<std::time_t>(diff.TotalSeconds);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more direct review of my code, but you're absolutely right, in this context I might as well assume `std::time_t` to be what Microsoft wanted it to be and keep the code to a minimum. Thanks for the elaborate answer.

Comment: time_t is in seconds, but you are adding the value as milliseconds. I think you should use `AddSeconds` and `TotalSeconds`.

Comment: Great answer but it should be .AddSeconds instead of .AddMilliSeconds.  Also for local time use DateTime::Local instead of DateTime::Utc.

Comment: Fixed for seconds, but I think I need to stick with UTC.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution my team arrived at:

DateTime represents the number of mixed-fractional days since midnight December 30, 1899, expressed as a double. I believe that this epoch date was used to account for the fact that 1900 was *not* a leap year, and it allows for an extra two days (Why two and not one? - It is not clear to me why Dec 31, 1899 was not chosen as their epoch.)

So a DateTime of 2.50 would be equivalent to January 1, 1900 12:00:00 , (i.e. the fraction represents 1/2 the day - 12PM).

We calculated that Jan 1, 1970 - the Unix Epoch - is 25569 days after the DateTime Epoch.

So the equivalent formula would be:

```
#include <time.h>
System::DateTime toDateTime(time_t &t)
{
    return 25569.0 + t / 86400.0; // ensure you use floating point math or you will truncate the fractional portion
}
```

Comment: The Microsoft documents says this about the one-parameter DateTime constructor:

A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

What information are you referring to?

Comment: `Why two and not one? - It is not clear to me why Dec 31, 1899 was not chosen as their epoch.)` I think Dec. 30 might be a mistake/typo because I cannot find any information about it actually being Dec. 30 rather than Dec. 31. In fact, I can find at least [one reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h.aspx) to Microsoft using Dec. 31, 1899 as an epoch, but none for Dec. 30.

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

Comment: Yes!  That would explain the 1 day discrepancy.  Great find!

So you can correct my statement.  It really does start on January 0, 1900, (i.e. Dec 31, 1899)   But Feb 29, 1900 mistakenly exists!

Talk about folklore...