# Create a string from c++11 time_t that is convertable to .net DateTime

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, datetime

This is a follow up question to this question:
[Standard conformant way of converting std::time_t to System::DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265481/standard-conformant-way-of-converting-stdtime-t-to-systemdatetime)

I need to convert a c++11 `time_t` to .NET `DateTime` by a string. The program needs to take the value of the current `time_t`, create a string which is going to be written to a file, and then another program which is written in C# is going to read that value and convert it to `DateTime`.

The problem is that I don't have access to the C# code so I need to make the needed string in the c++ side. Currently, the C# side knows how to convert strings in this format:

```
2018-05-13T10:03:18.4195735+03:00
```

I'm not sure if this is a regular conventional string that represents a `DateTime` and how exactly to create it.

Edit: In addition to the `time_t` value I also got the milliseconds value as a `chrono::seconds::rep` so you can just assume I got both

Comment: While time-keeping using `time_t` is implementation defined, on most systems it's the number of seconds (as an integer) from some epoch. That means you can never get the *exact* format you want, since that includes fractions of a second, which is then not possible with `time_t`. If you need fractions of a second you need to use platform-specific functions to get the date and time. For example [`GetSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows. Once you have that, it's just a question of formatting the string correctly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am currently also saving the milliseconds so you can assume I got both time_t and the milliseconds value

Answer (score 2):

This is the ISO 8601 format, an international standard to represente date and time.

In your case, you have `<date>T<time><zone>`

```
<date> = 2018-05-13 (YYYY-MM-DD)
<time> = 10:03:18.4195735 (hh:mm:ss.sssssss)
<zone> = +03:00
```

You can see more information about this convention here: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Probably they're using something to parse it to `DateTime`.

I don't know much about C++, but looks like you can use [`GetTimeZoneInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the timezone (Windows only). The time and date I think you already have, though they're asking for more precision than milliseconds. Looks like you can get only 1/1000000 of second in C++ with `chrono` (one [nanosecond](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/nanoseconds/)), which would be 6 decimal places. Do they really need it so precise? If not you can just add a 0 in the 7th decimal place.

Comment: @hvd Thank you, I updated the answer. I had not noticed that it's Windows only.